# How Vuetify translates fill-height prop to CSS ".fill-height" class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

There is a `fill-height` prop that I can use on `v-container` to make it fill the whole height of the container. It turns out that this `fill-height` prop is translated to the CSS class:

```
.fill-height {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is what I mean:
[image]
This code snippet is available [here](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/QWGmqeQ?editors=1010).

So it seems that I can use either `fill-height` prop or set `class=".fill-height"` but I was wondering how Vuetify does this? Is there some feature in Vue to translate props to CSS class?
[I tried searching through Vuetify source code for "fillHeight"](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/search?q=fillHeight&type=code) and I found one prop defined in some common variables file, but I couldn't figure out how this translates to `.fill-height` CSS class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VContainer component simply treats all attributes as CSS classes (except `slot` and `data-xxx` attributes) - look at the source code https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/78567e4e72973e2ff2acdcf3707c093bb9f0725c/packages/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/VContainer.ts#L29

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be good if these kind of things are documented in Vuetify docs but they are not :(

Comment: Yeah, the Vuetify documentation has issues. Pages which used to work suddenly start showing error 404, props that are mentioned in the component docs are actually ignored by the component, props have shitty description (or no description), etc.